# Select first valid expression

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I'm trying to write a function that would allow me to run the first valid expression from a list of expressions, some of which are potentially invalid. This would, **for example**, allow for uniform treatment of containers, some of which may have `emplace_back`, but some only `emplace`.

Here's my current implementation, using [`is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

```
template <typename F1, typename... Fs>
class select {
  template <typename... Args>
  using expr_t = decltype(F1{}(std::declval<Args>()...));
  template <typename... Args>
  constexpr static bool ok1 = is_detected<expr_t,Args...>::value;
public:
  template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<ok1<Args...>>* = nullptr>
  inline decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
    return F1{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<!ok1<Args...>>* = nullptr>
  inline decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Fs),"cannot select valid implementation");
    return select<Fs...>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

#define MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(NAME,EXPR) \
  struct NAME { \
    template <typename X, typename... Args> \
    inline auto operator()(X&& x, Args&&... args) \
    -> decltype(EXPR) { return EXPR; } \
  };
```

Here's a usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(emplace_back, x.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(emplace, x.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> v;
  std::map<std::string,std::string> m;

  select<emplace_back,emplace>{}(v,std::make_pair("hello","world"));
  select<emplace_back,emplace>{}(m,std::make_pair("hello","world"));
}
```

My question is whether a more elegant implementation or abstraction is possible. I particularly dislike the fact that I have repeat `EXPR` twice, once for the return type deduction with `decltype`, and another time in the function's body.

Using this with member functions on containers is **just an example**.
The general idea is to use this construct to specify a list of default code snippets to attempt on *a priori* unknown arguments.
Another example would be to conditionally either print with `std::cout << x;`, or to print the type of `x`, or some default message.

Comment: Look at [Boost Hana](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-sfinae)

Comment: And a third time if you want your function to be `noexcept` when possible...

Comment: @aschepler Don't you mean `noexcept` when possible?

Comment: @Justin Oops. Yes, yes I do.

Comment: It does not make much sense... All STL containers have a specific purpose are intended to be used in a specific way. It is obvious that `emplace` and `emplace_back` don't do the same thing. The latter always add items at the end...

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for Working code.

Comment: @Phil1970 I could certainly imagine a situation in which a template would want to "stick something into" a container and `std::vector::emplace_back` and `std::map::emplace` would be analogous to each other.

Comment: fwiw, I think the repetition of EXPR is fine, since it's squirreled away in a macro. I'm a lot more concerned about the magic `x` and `args` identifiers imposed on the users.

Comment: @SamMarinelli If you add something to a map, you need both key and value so they are not interchangeable... If you are unsure how to store data, then I would create a class that manage the data without leaking the internal container(s).

Comment: @Phil1970 But as the example shows, since a `map` is just a container of `std::pairs`s, the same `pair` object can be inserted into both containers.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't reuse the first argument to the macro, since all the 'magic' arguments are the same.

Comment: @SamMarinelli But usually, if you use a `vector`, you won't use a pair as it decrease the readability of code. One would probably use a `struct` where members are name intuitively for its problem. `first` and `second` are rarely good name. Another difference is how duplicate are handled. In a map, you cannot insert duplicates so often you first have to verify if an item exist. No one would do that kind of check with an unsorted `vector` as it would severely affect the performance. Also, if the container is change, it is best to leave the compiler find problems. OP suggestion goes against that.

Comment: I think the purpose of the example is mostly just to show the syntax with which `select` is used.  And it's hard to argue that there's no application for which accessing `map`s and `vector`s like this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most to the point comment was provided by [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896169), to

> look at [Boost Hana](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-sfinae).

The abstraction most expressively modeling this situation is to put a potentially valid expression in the context of a `maybe` monad, and then to compose the resulting objects (i.e. to define the bind operator, as it's called in Haskell) to run the first `maybe<function>` that's not `nothing` (i.e. valid). That's what `hana::sfinae` does, at least the first part, putting in the `maybe` context.

In my opinion, this is a better abstraction, because it builds up on smaller ideas, which can be composed in more ways than, allowing to solve a bigger class of problems

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reuse the first argument to the macro ??

As in:

```
#define MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(NAME)                         \
  struct NAME {                                          \
    template <typename X, typename... Args>              \
    inline auto operator()(X&& x, Args&&... args)        \
    -> decltype(x. NAME (std::forward<Args>(args)...))   \
       { return x. NAME (std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
  };
```

You can use macro programming tricks to have a macro with a variable number of arguments, this works for gcc, and ms compilers.

```
#define MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP_IMPL(NAME, EXPR, ...)         \
    struct NAME {                                        \
      template <typename X, typename... Args>            \
      inline auto operator()(X&& x, Args&&... args)      \
      -> decltype(EXPR) { return EXPR; }                 \
    };

#define MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(NAME, ...)                    \
    MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP_IMPL(NAME, ## __VA_ARGS__, x.NAME(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) 

// call as    

MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(emplace_back);

// or
MEMFCN_SFINAE_WRAP(emplace, x.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

Comment: Because `NAME` and the name of the member functions only coincide in this example. In general, the expression may be more complicated. Calling member functions is just a usage example.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but you are concentrating on a problem that's tangential to the problem in question.

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the problem the right way.  What you really want to end up typing is `emplace_back(container, value);`  not `select<emplace, something>{}(...)`

Comment: I don't see how your macro allows for this syntax, nor how the `emplace_back(container, value);` syntax allows to select either `emplace` or `emplace_back`.

Comment: 1) The macro trick shows how to define a default argument, and only demonstrates how you could avoid typing EXPR, in the most common cases, and only in the context of the original question ...  2)  Writing an emplace_back(container, value) template overload; using SFINAE, is rather trivial, compared to to the rather complex mechanics of the select<> template.  The resulting user code would also be much easier to read.